# Comparing modules available in different Strawberry Perl versions?

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan, strawberry-perl

Background: We have recently got into some confusion, because one developer used Strawberry Perl 5.14.4.1 while the our buildserver uses 5.14.2. However, 5.14.4.1 contains more modules, so the script didn't work on the server. Fix is obvious: Use the right (==same) version either way, or install missing modules from CPAN, but ...

I've been wondering, the Strawberry Homepage only seems to list ["List of distributions installed on top of ..."](http://strawberryperl.com/release-notes/5.14.4.1-32bit.html) or ["List of distributions added to ..."](http://strawberryperl.com/release-notes/5.14.2.1-32bit.html), so there doesn't seem a quick online way to compare what's in there.

Downloading the portable versions and doing a directory tree diff isn't too hard, but simple full lists than could be compared would be nice. Is there anything I have missed, or is the full list of modules included in a Strawberry Perl Release not available online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From each Strawberry installation, I'd start with the output of `cpan -a`, which creates an auto bundle of everything installed. From there you have the lists of what's actually there, including anything that you upgraded or added yourself:

```
Package namespace         installed    latest  in CPAN file
Algorithm::Diff              1.1902    1.1902  TYEMQ/Algorithm-Diff-1.1902.tar.gz
Alt::Crypt::RSA::BigInt        0.05      0.05  DANAJ/Alt-Crypt-RSA-BigInt-0.05.tar.gz
App::cpanminus               1.7001    1.7001  MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.7001.tar.gz
App::local::lib::Win32Helper     0.990     0.990  CSJEWELL/App-local-lib-Win32Helper-0.990.tar.gz
App::module::version          1.004     1.004  KMX/App-module-version-1.004.tar.gz
AppConfig                      1.66      1.66  ABW/AppConfig-1.66.tar.gz
Archive::Extract               0.70      0.72  BINGOS/Archive-Extract-0.72.tar.gz
Archive::Tar                   1.96      1.96  BINGOS/Archive-Tar-1.96.tar.gz
Archive::Zip                   1.36      1.37  PHRED/Archive-Zip-1.37.tar.gz
Attribute::Handlers            0.94      0.96  SMUELLER/Attribute-Handlers-0.96.tar.gz
```

From there you can reduce that by extracting what you want.

Note that this is imperfect since some modules don't set a version, so multiple versions of the same file will have the version 'undef'.